# css grid item positioning

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I'm learning CSS grid and trying to understand how it works. I've defined the grid template area like this:

```
grid-template-areas:
  "header header"
  "about contact"
  "latest status";
grid-template-columns: 70% 30%;
```

How can I set my grid template row value so that it fills up empty spaces? 
[image: grid screen shot]

Comment: Can you provide your whole code and an image, what you exactly want to achieve?

Comment: i want the status grid to start render from the empty space above it has

Comment: Why don't you just span the *About Me* section over two rows?

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1):

You need make the areas span multiple rows as well as multiple columns to make this work. The grid won't allow objects to just flow upwards (unless you're going to be using javascript), but with the static layout you're working with, this solution should be fine:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 20px;
 }

.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas:
    "header header"
    "about contact"
    "about status"
    "latest status";
  grid-template-columns: 70% 30%;
  grid-template-rows: 200px auto auto 200px;
  grid-gap: 20px;
}

.grid > div:not(.status) {
  background-color: #DDD;
  padding: 20px;
}

.header {
  grid-area: header;
}

.about {
  grid-area: about;
}

.contact {
  grid-area: contact;
}

.latest {
  grid-area: latest;
}

.status {
  grid-area: status;
}

.status-box {
  background-color: #DDD;
  padding: 20px;
}

h3 {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="header"><h3>header<h3></div>
  <div class="about"><h3>about</h3><br>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus in vulputate eros, vitae rhoncus odio. Nunc a justo eget odio aliquam hendrerit. Duis tristique, tellus nec cursus semper, risus turpis pretium mauris, ac venenatis elit massa vel ante. Etiam laoreet quam non nisl imperdiet ultricies. Donec vel suscipit erat. Phasellus id cursus ante. Sed lacinia, nisl in tincidunt molestie, nunc tortor scelerisque magna, sed imperdiet odio nunc in est.</div>
  <div class="contact">
    <h3>contact</h3><br>
    location<br>
    email<br>
    phone number<br>
   </div>
  <div class="latest"><h3>latest</h3></div>
  <div class="status">
    <div class="status-box">
      <h3>status</h3><br>
      current job<br>
      open for consultation
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**A couple things to notice:**

(1) `.about` spans two rows, both of which are height `auto`. This allows the likely smaller blocks in the right column to share the about section's height. If for whatever reason `.contact` is taller than `.about`, this layout starts to look screwy. So I'd apply a default height to `.about` to keep that from happening.

(2) `.status` appears like it's floating happily up to meet the bottom of `contact`. `.status` actually needed to span the `.about` and `.latest` rows because there's a high likelihood that the combined height of `.contact` and `.status` is greater than `.about`. Therefore, in order to prevent `.status` from looking super tall, I just nested the "real" `.status` block one level lower to change the visual size of the block, even though the height of the grid stretches all the way to the bottom of `.latest`.

Hopefully this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can use CSS Grid to do what you want.
In CSS Grid, you have to think of is has having rows and columns. A row can have cells with different height content, but the row will have the height of it's biggest cell. That is why your "status" is starting lower than the end of the "contact" content.

Maybe for what you want to do, using two columns would be a better idea.

Comment: Do you mean that using two rows would be better?

Comment: I mean you could have the "Basic Information" and the "Employement Status" in the same cell, and then have that cell span more than one row if needed